# In a finite group, how many elements x are in G with the following property : (and what about an infinite group? )

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In a finite group $G$, how many elements $x$ are in $G$ such that $x^5=e$? where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

I've seen that the no. of those elements in a $G$ is **multiple of 5**. But how I prove it...?

If the order of the group is **infinite**, what can you say about the no. of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$..?

Comment: It depends on the group?! In $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, there are none.

Comment: Very weird question! it is like someone asks how many seats does an airplane have?!

Comment: There must exists such element. It's identity element of G. How you say **martini** there are no such element.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_5$ there are $4$ elements of order 5, and $5$ elements such that $5x=0$. There is a difference between finding the order of an element and finding some $n$ such that $x^n=e$.

Comment: The OP doesn't talk about order of an element. So he's right, it's one or a multiple of $5$.

Comment: You mean he's not right, because he didn't mention $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is

> In a finite group $G$, the number of solutions of $x^5=e$ in $G$ is either $1$ or a multiple of $5$.

This follows from a [nice theorem by Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%27s_theorem_(group_theory)):

> If $n$ divides the order of a finite group $G$, then the number of solutions of $x^n=e$ in $G$ is a multiple of $n$.

Indeed, any solution of $x^5=1$ must either be $e$ or have order $5$. Therefore, if $5$ does not divide the order of $G$, then there is only the trivial solution $x=e$. If $5$ divides the order of $G$, then we can use Frobenius.

The same argument works for any prime instead of $5$.

Frobenius' theorem is proved in the book *The Theory Of Groups* by Marshall Hall Jr., section 9.1. The proof, which takes only two pages, is actually for a more general statement about solutions of $x^n=c$ for $c$ in a conjugacy class.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303848/divisor-of-a-finite-group.

Comment: Thanks... Now it's clear to me...

Comment: By the way,  if the order of the group is infinite, what can you say about the no. Of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$..?

Comment: @B.R.Datt, I don't know anything about the infinite case, sorry.